# Set an executable as a default application

Tags: command-line, nautilus

Suppose I have a file, `example.custom`, for which there is no application available in `Ubuntu Software` to open it. However, I DO have an executable `custom_viewer` (not installed via `Ubuntu Software`) that I would like to open the file when I click on it in Nautilus.

So for instance, on the command line, I would typically run

```
custom_viewer -options example.custom
```

to have `custom_viewer` open the file.

How do I get Nautilus to run the above command when I click on `example.custom`?

Comment: In Nautilus right click on the file you want to run and select Open with or Open with another application and it will remember your selection in the future.

Comment: Right. That shows you programs installed via the software center

Comment: I want to open with a program not installed via the software center